# How to map two different urls in a Akka-HTTP: one url with param and the same without the param?

Tags: scala, rest, akka-http

I want to define 2 different GET REST endpoints with same URI, one without any query parameters and another with query parameters.

Ex:

*http://host:port/resource/resourceID*   (uri without query parameter)

*http://host:port/resource/resourceID?key=value*  (uri with query parameter)

How can I achieve above requirement in Akka-HTTP with scala, and also need Segment(resource ID) in URI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your uri can be with or without query parameter, you can do something like

```
path("resource" / Segment) { resourceId => 
    parameter("key".optional) { value => //value of type Option[String]
       ???
    }
}
```

From the [doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameters.html)

> "color".optional
> (symbolic notation "color".?)
> extract the optional value of parameter “color” as Option[String]

Answer (score 0):

Solution form @ccheneson worked for me.

If u are using Akka-HTTP version greater than 10.2.0 then use
below solution

```
path("resource" / Segment) { resourceId => 
    parameter("key".optional) { value => //value of type Option[String]
       ???
    }
}
```

else use below solution

```
path("resource" / Segment) { resourceId => 
        parameter("key".?) { value => //value of type Option[String]
           ???
        }
    }
```